# Optimize nested switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

Since having nested switch cases is not very readable, how can I optmize my nested switch case?

```
switch (code) {
  case 200:
    switch (status) {
      case 'EXISTS':
        $alreadyExistsMessage.show();
        break;
      case 'UPDATED':
        $alreadyExistsMessage.show();
        break;
      case 'ERROR':
        $wrongFormatMessage.show();
        break;
    }
    break;
  case 201:
    redirectOnSuccess(data);
    break;
  default:
    $wrongFormatMessage.show();
    break;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it...

Comment: Either you do what you have or you call functions...

Comment: Call a function with switch-case inside case's.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong with what you're doing, but if it annoys you and you want more readable, just concatenate the two strings in the variable, and make it one big switch.

Comment: Saw the neat switch statement on [this](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html) page and it reminded me of this question.

Answer (score 2):

the only thing I would do is to combine case `'UPDATED'` and `'EXISTS'` due to the same block:

```
switch (code) {
  case 200:
    switch (status) {
      case 'EXISTS':
      case 'UPDATED':
        $alreadyExistsMessage.show();
        break;
      case 'ERROR':
        $wrongFormatMessage.show();
        break;
    }
    break;
  case 201:
    redirectOnSuccess(data);
    break;
  default:
    $wrongFormatMessage.show();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be creating a "map" to codes and status.

In this example you have a `callbacks` variable that acts like a map. You then access the properties by `code`. If that property is a function then run it, otherwise use the `status` to retrieve the property containing the function.

```js
/* mocks */
var code = 200;
var status = 'UPDATED';

var $alreadyExistsMessage =
  $wrongFormatMessage = {
    show: () => {
      console.log(code, status, callback[code][status]);
    }
  };

/* code */

var callback = {
  '200': {
    'EXISTS': $alreadyExistsMessage.show,
    'UPDATED': $alreadyExistsMessage.show,
    'ERROR': $wrongFormatMessage.show
  },
  'default': $wrongFormatMessage.show
};

var fn = callback[`${code}`];


if (typeof fn === 'function') {
  fn();
}
else if (!fn) {
  fn = callbacks['default'];
  fn();
}
else {
  fn = fn[status];
  fn();
}
```